# Bash - Fixing messy output

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, regex

I'm not sure how/why this is happening. Basically I have a command that is supposed to find and clean out all files in the desktop that contain a certain pattern. I am doing the first part using:

```
find . -iregex '.*._.*'
```

When I run this by itself, the output is normal i.e. it shows all files that contain that pattern. ex:

```
./Graph/CMPT 215/makefiles/._makefile6
./Graph/CMPT 215/makefiles/._example3.cmds
./Graph/CMPT 215/makefiles/._makefile5
./Graph/CMPT 215/makefiles/._makefile1
./Graph/CMPT 215/makefiles/._makefile4
./Graph/CMPT 215/makefiles/._makefile2
./Graph/CMPT 215/makefiles/._makefile3
...
```

However I want to delete all these files, so after some google search, I came up with this:

```
rm -rf $(find . -iregex '.*._.*')
```

But the problem is that when I run this command, I get the following output:

```
rm: cannot remove â?~215/makefiles/._makefile6â?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~./Graph/CMPTâ?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~215/makefiles/._example3.cmdsâ?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~./Graph/CMPTâ?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~215/makefiles/._makefile5â?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~./Graph/CMPTâ?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~215/makefiles/._makefile1â?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~./Graph/CMPTâ?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~215/makefiles/._makefile4â?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~./Graph/CMPTâ?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~215/makefiles/._makefile2â?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~./Graph/CMPTâ?T: No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove â?~215/makefiles/._makefile3â?T: No such file or directory
...
```

I looked online and it was suggested to reset the terminal by typing `reset`, but this has not fixed it. What can I do to make sure the output to `rm` is correct?

If it helps, I am on Windows and using ssh to connect to a remote machine running Linux Mageia and deleting some files on the machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work: `find . -iregex '.*._.*' -exec rm {} \;`.

The results of the `find` command will be sent to the `rm` command as its argument, `{}` is the placeholder for that argument, `\;` is to complete the `-exec` flag of the find function.

More info on the find command [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Comment: Ok that worked, but why was the command I used producing the weird output it was?

Comment: There could be many answers to that question.  Likely was caused by the spaces in the file path.  It boils down to the command substitution `$(find . -iregex '.*._.*')` echoing invalid characters, falsifying the file path that `rm` was trying to use. The find command escapes those characters before passing it to the `rm` command in this case. FYI: be VERY careful with `rm -rf`, it's easy to remove things you do not want to be removed, like the `/` directory.

Comment: Is there an alternative to rm?

Comment: Just do not use the `-f` flag to force it unless you are 100% sure of what you are removing.

Comment: And the other general lesson that you should learn from this experience is not to use the output of `find` (which does `-print` by default) for anything but viewing by a sentient life form. If you must pass the list of files to some other program, use `-print0` (which writes the pathnames separated by nuls instead of newlines) and pass it to one of the few programs that can handle that (e.g., `xargs`, with the `-0` option). If you simply want to do something to each found file, use `-exec` (or `-delete`, if appropriate, and if your version of `find` supports it).

Comment: The errors were caused by the embedded blank, as @Ray says. The weird characters are because the remote shell is using extended characters in its error messages (forward and backward quotes, E2/80/98 and E2/80/99) and these are not recognised when the errors are displayed in Windows (the codes do not quite correspond, but I put this down to some attempt at mapping the individual characters).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use xargs command with find like that:

> `find . -iregex '.*._.*' | xargs rm -rf`

`find` will collect all unneeded files in one string and `xargs rm -rf` will delete all the file paths from those string. It is more efficient to use xargs with find then `-exec` option because it will run `rm -rf` only ones unike with `-exec` option.

Comment: I tried xargs, but some of the files contain the `'` character so xargs tries to interpret that as something else